# How do I do `mysql_affected_rows()` in Python `dataset` library

Tags: python, mysql

How do I do `mysql_affected_rows()` in Python `dataset` library?

- `dataset` library: https://dataset.readthedocs.org
- Running SQL queries: https://dataset.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#running-custom-sql-queries

Answer (score 0):

`table.update()` method returns number of updated rows:

```
affected_rows = table.update({"foo", "bar", "id": 10}, ['id'])
```

Comment: Is there document about the return values of `insert`, `update`, and `upsert`? In my program I'm mainly using `upsert`. Your answer inspires me  (tks for that!) but doesn't entirely solve my problem.

Comment: @JennyaChang I've found this in the source code https://dataset.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/dataset/persistence/table.html#Table.update